# How does Jorah know who this is?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones season 5 episode 3, "[*High Sparrow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Sparrow)," we see:

> Tyrion and Varys, on their way to see Daenerys Targaryen, stop by a brothel in Volantis where Tyrion is kidnapped by Jorah Mormont. How did Jorah know this was Tyrion Lannister and not some random dwarf? Jorah fled Westeros decades ago, so there is no way he would know what Tyrion would look like.

Comment: Westerosi midget walking around a whorehouse with Varys... Nah couldn't possibly be Tyrion!

Comment: @Mooz How would you know if it's a Westerosi dwarf or any other random dwarf?

Comment: Tyrion was talking *in Westerosi*. It's not as clear in the shows, but people very clearly pick-out the different accents in the books.

Comment: @Mooz **Westerosi midget** with **no nose**...

Answer (score 27):

The only possible location where Jorah Mormont could have met

> Tyrion Lannister

is the [Tourney at Lannisport](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tourney_at_Lannisport), where Jorah Mormont came out victorious, in the final he broke nine lances against Ser Jaime Lannister. This event is described in the Books. And in GoT season 5 episode 6, when Jorah and

> Tyrion are taken captive by slavers, Tyrion claims that Jorah unseated Jaime Lannister in a jousting match.

Comment: I changed your spoiler tags so that less of the answer is hidden.

Comment: I don't think Jorah mormont even had to ever see Tyrion Lannister. See [my answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/91006/33716) about why.

Comment: this makes the most sense, and tyrion was very supportive of jamie so he had a high probability of being at this tournament and in prominent view being a lannister.

Comment: >! Jorah Mormont tells about that tournament in the TV series too. (I can't recall the concrete episode.)

Answer (score 24):

Jorah didn't flee Westeros "decades ago". He was a hero in the Greyjoy Rebellion, only nine years before the start of the series. Since the Lannisters also played a major part in that war, it doesn't seem unlikely that Jorah might have seen or even met a younger Tyrion. If Tyrion is the same age as Peter Dinklage, then he was 31 during the Greyjoy Rebellion and 40 at the start of the series.

Comment: Not that this necessarily means anything for the show (since the young characters are all older), but according to AWOIAF Tyrion was born [in 273](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_273_After_the_Conquest), the Greyjoy rebellion was [in 289](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_289_After_the_Conquest) (making Tyrion about 16), and this book is [in 300](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest#Year_300_After_the_Conquest) (making him about 27).

Answer (score 16):

Soft spoiler from the 5. SOIAF book (and the mentioned episode)

> The answer might be that in the series Tyrion is a lot less characteristic than in the books. In the books by this time he literally has no nose and I guess a blonde midget with no nose who drinks a lot, behaves like he owns the place, and speaks the common tongue of Westeros is not a common sight. Also there is a huge bounty on Tyrion's head and he surely fled fron the Seven Kingdoms, so I guess it is just basic logic.

Comment: Jorah would also have no reason to know about the mutilated nose... (the mismatched eyes might be a giveaway though)

Comment: @user568458 Since there is a bounty on Tyrion's head I think drawings - but descriptions at least - are sent out to all over the known lands.

Answer (score 1):

Jorah was

> expelled from Danaerys' circle for having been an informant to Westeros.

He may have more ties to the West than we're inclined to believe.

Not to mention the points mentioned above:

> the bounty on Tyrion's head across the known world, his disfigurement and his accent when speaking Valyrian.

Comment: I don't think that this tie to Westeros would provide him with description of Tyrion and other Westerosian gossips  :D